# Convergence to exponential function.

Tags: calculus

I saw an exercise like this:

> .. conclude that if 
>   $$\max_{1 \le j  \le n} \left|c_{j,n}\right| \to 0,$$ 
>   $$\sum_{j=1}^n c_{j,n} \to \lambda,$$
>   $$\sup_n \sum_{j=1}^n \left|c_{j,n}\right|< \infty$$
>   then we have
>   $$
> \prod_{j=1}^n (1+c_{j,n}) \to e^{\lambda}.
> $$

My proof goes like this: Given $\epsilon > 0$ when $n$ is large enough, we have
$$
\left| \frac {\log (1+c_{j,n})} {c_{j,n}}-1 \right| \le \epsilon.
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \log (1+c_{j,n}) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac {\log (1+c_{j,n})} {c_{j,n}} c_{j,n} \le (1+\epsilon) \sum_{j=1}^n c_{j,n}.
$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, let $n \to \infty$ gives
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \log (1+c_{j,n}) \le \lambda.
$$
With symmetric argument, we have
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \log (1+c_{j,n}) \ge \lambda.
$$
So we are done.

The strange thing about this proof is that the condition
$$\sup_n \sum_{j=1}^n \left|c_{j,n}\right|< \infty$$
is not used in the proof. So what mistake did I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^nc_{j,n}^2
&\le\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\max_{1\le j\le n}|c_{j,n}|\right)\sup_n\sum_{j=1}^n|c_{j,n}|\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\log(1+c_{j,n})
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(c_{j,n}+O(c_{j,n}^2)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^nc_{j,n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^nO(c_{j,n}^2)\\
&=\lambda+0
\end{align}
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+c_{j,n}\right)=e^\lambda
$$

---

In your proof you have correctly claimed that for small enough $x$
$$
\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\le1+\epsilon
$$
However, the problem happens when you multiply by $x$, which may be positive or negative, to claim that
$$
\log(1+x)\le(1+\epsilon)x
$$
Since the slope of $\log(1+x)$ is $1$ near $0$, the latter inequality cannot hold for any $\epsilon\ne0$ for both positive and negative $x$.